# .__MAXOS folder when unziping (in context of XCode project)

Tags: xcode, macos, unzip

I came across a problem when performing such a sequence of actions:

- Downloading xCode project from some tutorials website (.zip file)
- Extracting project (unzip ProjectName.zip)
- Opening extracted project in XCode and changing something in the code. After some changes project reports some runtime errors - does not matter what kind...
- Closing the XCode, deleting the project (rm -rf Projectname)
- Unzipping it once again
- Problem: runtime errors still exists despite the fact old project has been deleted

After a couple of hours I found, that when unzipping from terminal level, MacOS creates some hidden catalog named .__MacOSX or so (http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/08/unzipping-files-using-terminal.html) Deleting the project from that hidden directory (Projectname catalog) was helpful.

Question:
Have you ever faced this problem and do you know what kind of data are stored in that hidden directory (especially in context of XCode project)? Do the files from that hidden directory have impact of the unzipping process (using unzip command) ?

Comment: So why didn't `rm -rf` remove the `__MacOSX` folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The __MACOSX folder stores [AppleDouble files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleDouble). When you create a .zip archive in the Finder, it uses these to store all the file metadata that the zip archive format doesn't natively handle. If you expand the .zip with the Finder (actually, it uses the Archive Utility) it reattaches the metadata to the files rather than expanding the __MACOSX folder as separate files. If you use the command-line unzip tool, it doesn't know what to do with the AppleDouble files, and thus expands them as separate files.

It's possible to remerge the AppleDouble files (e.g. with the [FixupResourceForks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/FixupResourceForks.1.html) utility), but it's generally best to just use the Finder to expand Mac .zip archives and let it reassemble everything properly.